# Next / previous arrows to cycle through divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add two arrows to the sides of the "boxes" divs (below) to cycle through the 3 divs.

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/HBHcC/11/

Can someone help me with this?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="boxes">
        <div class="one box">
        </div>
        <div class="two box">
        </div>
        <div class="three box">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

.box {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.one{
    background-color:green;
}
.two{
    background-color:red;
}
.three{
    background-color:blue;
}
.boxes{
    width:400px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').on("click", function() {
        // Is this the last div, or is there a next one?
        if ($(this).next().length) {            
            var animSpeed = 200;  // Make this 0 for an instant change
            $('.boxes').animate({marginLeft : "-=100"}, animSpeed);
        }        
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi there. The format of this question is not appropriate for SO. Please read the posting guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't view it as "inappropriate", but it does demonstrate a bit of laziness.

Answer (score 3):

After adding arrows to the div, here is a new fiddle that should get you started:

```
   $('.rightarrow').on("click", function() {
      // Is this the last div, or is there a next one?
      var animSpeed = 200;  // Make this 0 for an instant change
      $('.boxes').animate({marginLeft : "-=100"}, animSpeed);     
   });

   $('.leftarrow').on("click", function() {
      // Is this the last div, or is there a next one?
      var animSpeed = 200;  // Make this 0 for an instant change
      $('.boxes').animate({marginLeft : "+=100"}, animSpeed);
   });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tx2yg06w/1/

Updated w/arrows moved out of divs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var animSpeed = 200;
  $('.rightarrow').on("click", function() {
    if(parseInt($("#boxes").css("marginLeft")) == -200){ return;}
    $('.boxes').animate({marginLeft : "-=100"}, animSpeed);     
  });

  $('.leftarrow').on("click", function() {
    if(parseInt($("#boxes").css("marginLeft")) == 0){ return;}
    $('.boxes').animate({marginLeft : "+=100"}, animSpeed);
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b56r0d72/

Comment: i want the arrow to be outside of the div.